# java ee app deploy to openshift gives 404 error

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, openshift

I have a Java EE app developed in eclipse and converted to maven. I've setup the rhc tools on my pc and pushed to git (including the webapps folder in my project with the project's war file). But when I try to access the site it says 404 - resource not available. How long does it take for openshift to update the git push commands from my pc? My Welcome file lists Startup.jsp as my start page. Should I rename this to index.jsp? What factors are there to consider?

Comment: Changing the name to index.jsp won't make any difference

Comment: I figured it out. I was using the wrong clone command.